# Solve the PDE $x^2U_{xx}+U_{yy}+U\log U=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the PDE $x^2U_{xx}+U_{yy}+U\log U=0$

my attempt:

this is elliptic  and $\lambda=\pm \frac{i}{x}$

so $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{i}{x}, \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-i}{x}$

from here to how to processed

Comment: I guess you mean $$x^{2} U_{xx} + \color{red}{U}_{yy} + U \log U = 0$$

Comment: What are the boundary and/or initial conditions for the PDE?

Comment: Also, are you only seeking an analytic solution? or will you also employ Numerical Methods?

Comment: @DavidG..trying to find with charctertic curves method

Comment: Separation of variables yields \begin{align} x^{2}X'' + X \log X &= - \lambda X \\ Y'' + Y \log Y &= \lambda Y \end{align} where the separation constant is $-\lambda$. However, as DavidG highlighted, you haven't specified any data with your PDE so we don't know whether this is a reasonable ansatz.